Cannot set nextjs 14 cookies in route handlers fetch call
In my program that written with nextjs 14, which I wrote with a route handler, a request is sent to the api and when the api response is executed successfully, a cookie is set, but this cookie is only set when I run localhost:3000/api/sessionCheck directly, but When I try to register through fetch, the cookies are not set.
  import { cookies } from "next/headers";
  import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
  export async function GET(request: Request) {
    const cookieStore = cookies(request);
    const existingSessionName = cookieStore.get("sessionName");

    if (existingSessionName) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        hasToken: true,
        message: "Session already exists",
        token: existingSessionName.value,
      });
    }

    const res = await fetch(
      "https://nest-jahizan.chbk.run/v1/api/ecommerce/user/sessions/generate",
      {
        method: "POST",
      }
    );

    if (!res.ok) {
      return new Response("Failed to generate session", { status: 500 });
    }

    const data = await res.json();
    console.log("arman", data);

    cookieStore.set("sessionName", data.result.id, {
      expires: new Date(data.result.expireAt),
    });

    return NextResponse.json({
      hasToken: true,
      token: data.result.id,
      message: "New session generated",
    });
  }

and this is my interceptor
"use server";

import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const getSessionName = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/sessionCheck`, {
    method: "GET",
  });
  return res.json();
};

export default async function Interseptor(url) {
  const result = await getSessionName();
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}${url}`, {
    cache: "no-store",
    headers: {
      "x-session-id": result.token,
    },
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return res;
}

in this codes when i checking the browser cookies, its not setting but when i direct opening the route.ts it setting the cookies.

try setting the cookies in NextResponse itself. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response#setname-value
